Isomorphic ring
Two rings $R_1$= $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{X^2}$ and  $R_2$= $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{X^2-1}$ are given I have to show whether they are isomorphic or not
Clearly both are not integral domain but I have not find any explicit isomorphism between them. Neither any criteria to show they are not isomorphic.
Any idea how to show?

Duplicate please search ....

Hint: What are the nilpotent elements in each ring?

I have used https://approach0.xyz/ to identify the duplicates. Please use that before asking. Thanks!
